# Outer routing switch - collisions and packet loss

Tags: routing, switch, packet-loss

Currently I have experienced collisions and packet loss on an outer routing switch (1-2% from the States and above 6% when tested from Europe). In a basic way infrastructure looks like 
[image]

Where outer switch is Netgear DS524 (previously some Linksys). NSA TS and NSA HA are Sonciwall 2400 family. Internet test gateway and WiFi are network devices before a firewall (a PC and a wireless guest AP).

I have tested if there are packet loss on VLANs behind a firewall but all work as should.

What can cause those packet loss on that outer switch? Any good suggestions for a hardware replacement (up to 8 ports, rack mountable)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Netgear DS524 is a hub, not a switch.  Collisions are part of life with hubs.  Switches separate collision domains per port, while hubs do not.

Hubs are layer-1 devices that constitute a single connection for all ports.

Switches are layer-2 devices that have separate connections for each port.

Comment: Yeah, I know that but I have switched from Linksys to Netgear because early packed loss on a Linksys and Netgear I just had on a shelf. Any good suggestion for a replacement? I will mark then as an answer

Comment: You are just going to need to live with collisions if you use a hub.

Comment: But packet loss coming from those collisions? If so I need to replace it back with a switch (any suggestion?)

Comment: You need a switch to avoid collisions. With a switch you avoid collisions, and a good managed switch can monitor the ports to give you errors that may result in packet loss. Product and resource recommendations are off-topic for this forum.

Comment: What can cause that huge differences in packet loss US vs Europe?

Comment: Without any more details on the errors causing the packet loss, there is no way to know. This is a separate question, and it should be asked in a new question. You could also take this discussion to the chat.